# How would I implement async into this api call?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I am trying to call a `fetch()` and then use the results in another `fetch()`, but I don't know how to use async. Currently, I am just delaying one second with `setTimeout`, but that doesn't always work.
for example:

```js
var response1;
var response2;
function wantToAsync() {
        fetch('example.com/fetchSearch?search' + searchString, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'KEY HERE',
                },
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                response1 = response;

            })
        //DON'T DO THIS:
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('example.com/fetchSearch2?search=' + response1, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'KEY HERE',
                    },
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    response2 = response
                })
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Every `.then()` call should be translated to one `await` expression. Can you show us your approach please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
async function searchForPlayer() {
  const searchString = document.getElementById("gunInput").value;
  const playerId = await fetch(
    "https://fortniteapi.io/v1/lookup?username=" + searchString,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "KEY HERE",
      },
    },
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => response.account_id);

  const result = await fetch(
    "https://fortniteapi.io/v1/stats?account=" + playerId,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "KEY HERE",
      },
    },
  ).then((response) => response.json());
  // do something with the result
}
```

Comment: what about the final `.then()`? other than that, looks good thx

Comment: You don't need that, you can just use the `result`

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: ah I see you made it a `const`

Comment: can you explain how this works so I can use it in future programs?